# Get absolute path of newest file containing string in filename in batch script

Tags: batch-file, windows-shell

I have a batch file that I would like to pick up the newest "manifest" file, so I was hoping to be able to use a for loop for that, but I'm not sure of the correct syntax.

This is what I have:

```
for /R %imagePath% %%F in (*.manifest.*) do (set manFile=%%F)
```

Which does the correct thing to return "C:/some/path/to/file.manifest.ext", but not necessarily the newest one. I see other questions like this one that use `dir`, but then I don't get the entire path. My attempt at doing this with `dir` looks like:

```
for /R %imagePath% %%F in ('dir /od *.manifest.*.*') do (set manFile=%%F)
```

This doesn't give me the output I was expecting.

What is the best way to accomplish this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```dos
set "manFile="
for /f "tokens=2,*" %%a in ('
    robocopy "%imagePath%" "%temp%" *.manifest.* /is /l /nocopy /s /njh /njs /ndl /nc /ns /ts
    ^| sort /r
') do if not defined manFile set "manFile=%%b"
```

This uses a `for /f` to process the output of a `robocopy` command that will generate a list of the matching files with a UTC timestamp that will be reverse sorted so the newest file will be the first in the list.

Comment: That is amazing. I don't think I would've ever thought to use `robocopy` to list the files. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

MC ND's solution is smart. But when I tried it out using "*.*" as the filemask I got a wrong result. The reasons is that `robocopy` lists corresponding files from *both* the source folder and the (dummy) target folder, in this case `%TEMP%`. You can fix that either by adding the `/xx` switch to `robocopy`, or just use an empty target folder. As I am not 100% sure that the `/xx` switch will always work I resorted to specifying a random name for the destination folder (which hopefully will not exist).

The second disadvantage of the original code is that the `FOR` loop will unnecessarily execute till the end of the list of files which can be arbitrary long.

The following code fixes the target folder problem, shortcuts the loop after the result is obtained, and in addition exports both the filename and the timestamp of the youngest file in the tree:

```
@echo off
setlocal

set "srcpath=%~1"
if not DEFINED srcpath set srcpath=%CD%
set /A skip=%2 - 1
set opt=
if DEFINED skip if %skip%0 GTR 0 set "opt=skip=%skip%"

set MASK=*.manifest.*
for /f "%opt% tokens=1,2*" %%a in ('
    robocopy "%srcpath%" %RANDOM%_%RANDOM% %MASK% /l /s /ts /njh /njs /ndl /nc /ns ^| sort /r
') do set "tstamp=%%a %%b" & set "youngestfile=%%c" & goto :ex

:ex
echo %youngestfile%    %tstamp%
```

The script now can take up to 2 arguments. The first argument is the source folder which defaults to the current folder if omitted. The second argument is numeric and allows to search for the nth youngest file. So for instance "lastfile . 2" would return the second youngest file in the tree rooted at the current folder. This is a side effect of the `FOR` loop starting at the top of list with the youngest files.